# Access UISwitch in Prototype Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I'm trying to print on/off when the user changes the state of my UISwitch.

[image]

For example

```
- (IBAction)toggleSwitch:(id)sender {

    ChannelsTableViewCell* cell = (ChannelsTableViewCell *)[sender superview].superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    if (cell.localSwitch.on)
    {
        NSLog(@"On");
    }

}
```

When I run this it throws an error.

2014-04-24 11:33:41.462 HRApp[3258:60b] -[UITableViewCellScrollView localTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19354410
2014-04-24 11:33:41.467 HRApp[3258:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellScrollView localTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19354410'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hook up the `IBAction` to the switch, you don't need to get the `UITableViewCell` to check for the switch's value. You can use the sender parameter from the `IBAction`. Hence:

```
- (IBAction)toggleSwitch:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *switch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    if (switch.on)
    {
        NSLog(@"On");
    }

}
```

If you need to find the `indexPath` at which the `UISwitch` is shown, you can add the following:

```
CGPoint pointInTable = [switch convertPoint:switch.bounds.origin toView:self.tableView];    
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTable];
```

Comment: That work perfectly! Ultimately if the state of the slider changes I want to update a value in my database. How can I get the cell title (cell.localtTitle) or index path row of the affected cell from the toggleSwitch action?

Comment: @user2920762 I edited the answer with a possible solution that will give you the indexPath from the sender.

Comment: I edited my answer. Notice I'm now casting sender to a `UISwitch` and using it instead.