# How to pass state of UISwitch in prototype cell back to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch in a prototype cell that I can't figure out how to pass the state back to my UITableView. I need the state of the switch passed back to update an object to reflect the new state.

I've tried the following questions but they are both in Objective C (I barely can write Swift so I'm struggling to work out how to adapt them)
[Access UISwitch in Prototype Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265291/access-uiswitch-in-prototype-cell) and
[How to retrieve UISwitch state in each of my UITableView cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595757/how-to-retrieve-uiswitch-state-in-each-of-my-uitableview-cells)

I'm currently attempting to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27661207/7708346) solution working.

Here is the perameters for building the cell in UITabelView:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProgrammeToggleTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ProgrammeToogleTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        cell.setTitle(text: programmes[indexPath.row].name)

        cell.programmeToggle.tag = indexPath.row
        print(cell.programmeToggle.tag)
        cell.programmeToggle.isOn = programmes[indexPath.row].active
        cell.programmeToggle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProgrammeTableViewController.switchAtValueChanged(programmeToggle: UISwitch, indexPath: IndexPath)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)

        return cell
    }
```

I later attempt to access the switch using the following:

```
    @objc func switchAtValueChanged(programmeToggle: UISwitch, indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if programmeToggle.tag == 1 {
            var programmes[indexPath.row].active = UISwitch.isOn
            print(programmes[1].active)
        }
    }
```

`programmes` is an array of objects.

The line `var programmes[indexPath.row].active = UISwitch.isOn` is currently giving me the following errors:
`Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'`
`Type annotation missing in pattern`
`Value of type '[Int]' has no member 'active'`

I'd like to use the state of the switch to edit a value of one of the objects in the `programmes` array. As I'm inexperienced with Swift I don't know if I'm barking up the wrong tree or if this is a feasible solution when working.

Thanks for any help, happy to provide any further information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create the call back in table view cell.

```
 class ProgrammeToogleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var switchUI: UISwitch!

   // callback to get action of switch status
   var callBackSwitchState:((Bool) -> (Void))?

  // Create action for value change event on switch
   @IBAction func switchAtValueChanged(programmeToggle: UISwitch) {
     callBackSwitchState?(programmeToggle.isOn)
   }
}
```

Now in your cellForRowAt data source method, you need to set the value for this callback that you just created to get the status for your switch:

In your table view class:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
  UITableViewCell {
   guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
     "ProgrammeToggleTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ProgrammeToogleTableViewCell 
     else { return UITableViewCell() }
    cell.tag = indexPath.row

    // Implement the callback to get the status of switch:
    cell.callBackSwitchState = { isOn in
    print("Your Switch status = \(isOn)")

    // isOn is your switch status. You can update your object here.
   }

 // Your other code here ....
 return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not as trivial as you tried it. When you dequeue a table view cell it means it will either create a new cell or reuse an old one. For instance you have 100 cells but can only see 10 at a same time. As user scrolls down the first cell disappears and it is then reused as 11th cell. So that is physically the same cell. And calling to add target-selector on its switch it would mean that you now have 2 actions on that switch. But as you probably found out you have other issues in this case anyhow (like not being able to inject index path into method).

You need to use table only as representation of data. So you must modify data elsewhere.

The simplest solution in your case is to add your class into the cell itself. Simply assign it in cell for row method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProgrammeToggleTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ProgrammeToogleTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    cell.programme = programmes[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Now put all the logic inside the cell like for instance:

```
var programme: Programme? {
    didSet {
        refresh()
    }
}
func refresh() {
    guard let programme = programme else { return }
    programmeToggle.isOn = programme.active
}

@IBAction private func switchToggled() {
    self.programme?.active = programmeToggle.isOn
}
```

Now the action of a switch effects the assigned progremme. In your case this should be enough.

As an alternative you in many cases need to use delegates. Your view controller would define a protocol that a switch has been toggled and you would assign it to your cell:

```
cell.progremmeID = progremme.id
cell.delegate = self
return cell
```

and then protocol:

```
func programmeCell(_ sender: ProgrammeToogleTableViewCell, didToggleProgremme programmeID: String, toActive flag: Bool) {
    programmes.first(where: { $0.id == programmeID })?.active = flag
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this one to work, had an issue with it returning nil when trying to access the object and crashing on launch. However your answer was very informative and I've learnt some good information from it regardless, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

just remove var following line-

var programmes[indexPath.row].active = UISwitch.isOn